# Loop through observable list

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

I have a javafx table (carTable) that contains a single column:

```
+-------------+
+ Brand        +
+-------------+
```

This column is part of an observable list (carOL). This OL also contains 2 Lists ("Dates" and "Prices"). For each brand prices can be downloaded from the internet for a specific time window.

eg:

```
Audi
   2014-01-01
   2014-01-02
   55000
   90000
BMW
   2014-01-01
   2014-01-02
   85000
   70000
```

I now want to create a line chart with all this data, that compares price development between the different brands.

What I have come up so far:

```
@FXML private CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
@FXML private NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
@FXML private LineChart<String, Number> lc = new LineChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);

Series<String, Number> series = new Series<>();
List<String> d = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Double> p = new ArrayList<Double>();
int id = 0;

for (Car c : carOL) {
    d = c.getDate(); // returns array list with dates from OL
    p = c.getPrice(); // returns array list with prices from OL
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(d.get(id), p.get(id)));
    id++;
    }

lc.getData().add(series);
```

This of course does not quite return what I want. I somehow need to be able to create separate "series" for each brand.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

If order of items in array of dates corresponds to order of items in array of prices, you need this:

```
for (Car c : carOL) { 
  d = c.getDate(); // returns array list with dates from OL 
  p = c.getPrice(); // returns array list with prices from OL 
  for (String dates : d.getDate()) { 
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(dates, p.get(id))); 
    id++; 
  } 
}
```

Go through all dates and add them with appropriate prices.

Comment: thanks, but that works quite well, as the date is already string formatted in my observation list

Comment: @double_o Ok, try add generic types when you initialise `series`, `new Series<String, Number>();`

Comment: @double_o And are you sure that `carOL` is not empty?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure carOL is not empty. I actually don't have problems adding the values. My problem is that I only get a single series, ie. one line in the line chart, instead of one for each brand.

Comment: @double_o `Car c` contains information like: Audi
   2014-01-01
   2014-01-02
   55000
   90000 ?

Comment: the Car class contains the observable list carOL, which contains all that data. there's nothing wrong with the data itself. i can open the line chart, see the dates on the x axis and the numbers on the y axis. At the moment I do only see one line (prices incorrect to due pulling data from all brands), although I want to see one line for Audi, one for BMW, etc...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55532/discussion-between-alexander-podkutin-and-double-o).